# Increase visibility of interface

Tags: java, kotlin, interface, visibility

I have two packages:

**1.** `com.test.hidden`:

Contains an **protected** interface `MyListener` and a public class `FancyClass` with a public method for registering `MyListener` objects:

```
package com.test.hidden;
public class FancyClass {
    public void registerListener(MyListener listener) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.test.hidden;
interface MyListener {
    void doSomething();
}
```

**2.** `com.test.myapp`:

Here I have an instance of `FancyClass` and I want to register a new `MyListener` object to it.

Obviously this will not work since `MyListener` is not visible in `com.test.myapp`. My intuition was to create a new interface in `com.test.hidden` that extends `MyListener` and is public:

```
package com.test.hidden;
public interface MyListenerWrapper extends MyListener {
    @Override
    void doSomething();
}
```

---

```
package com.test.myapp
import com.test.hidden.FancyClass
import com.test.hidden.MyListenerWrapper

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        val fc = FancyClass()
        fc.registerListener(object : MyListenerWrapper {
            override fun doSomething() {
                // ...
            }
        })
    }
}
```

But I get an `IllegalAccessError`:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Illegal class access: 'com.test.myapp.MainActivity' attempting to access 'com.test.hidden.MyListener' (declaration of 'com.test.myapp.MainActivity' appears in /data/app/com.test.myapp-ZzNlHhuBCCdAEV4QsZHspw==/base.apk)
        at com.test.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3054)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1814)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

When I change the visibility of `MyListener` to public it works just fine, so I suspect Java does not like increasing the visibility of interfaces in subinterfaces. Why doesn't this work and how to solve this?

Comment: I think this is a Kotlin thing. Java would usually allow it. The crux of the issue here is that you have a public method which exposes a package private type. `public void registerListener(MyListener listener)`. Either `MyListener` should be public, or this method should be package private. **Anything else** is bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin does not like exposing internal API's in public methods, and actually go as far as giving compiler errors if you do this. This also affects Java code if you call the code from Kotlin, but it throws an exception at runtime rather than at compile time.

As for solutions, Kotlin has `internal`, but this is a really special keyword: unlike Java's package private (no modifier), internal makes it visible everywhere in the module.

That's also one solution: convert to Kotlin and use `internal`. If you're making a library, it won't be visible outside the module, but you'll be able to declare it internally at least.

The second is converting the interface to a class and using a `sealed class`. Note that this requires all children to be declared in the same file. See [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) for more info on sealed classes.

And the final solution: make it public. I **highly** recommend you go with this over the other alternatives, mainly because it's the easiest option and the one that doesn't require hackish design. Also, if you're planning on accessing the interface somewhere else, you'd have to use specific implementations rather than the general superclass, which isn't always feasible (depends on your use though).

And there's also the option of only using Java, but I assume you'd prefer mixing since you're already doing that. But as [Michael mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912499/increase-visibility-of-interface#comment96592599_54912499), you should really avoid this kind of design: it's bad design. If I were you, I'd make it public either way.